# How to get context in FlutterActivity?

Tags: flutter

How to get context here? I keep getting null on my sharedPref because of context being null

````
  private val CHANNEL = "samples.flutter.dev/battery"
  private val sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(“”,Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

  override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
    MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler {
      call, result ->
      // Note: this method is invoked on the main thread.
      // TODO
    }
  }
} ```
````

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Create `SharedPreferencesHandler.java` file and add code below!

```
package com.example.package;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class SharedPreferencesHandler
{
    private static final String SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME = "com_example_package_data"; //You can change this to any other name
    private static final int SHARED_PREFERENCES_MOD = Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor;

    public SharedPreferencesHandler(Context context)
    {
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME, SHARED_PREFERENCES_MOD);
        preferencesEditor = preferences.edit();
    }

    public void put(String key, Object value)
    {
        if (value instanceof String)
            preferencesEditor.putString(key, (String) value);
        if (value instanceof Boolean)
            preferencesEditor.putBoolean(key, (boolean) value);
        if (value instanceof Float)
            preferencesEditor.putFloat(key, (float) value);
        if (value instanceof Integer)
            preferencesEditor.putInt(key, (int) value);
        if (value instanceof Long)
            preferencesEditor.putLong(key, (long) value);
    }


    public void apply()
    {
        preferencesEditor.apply();
    }


    public <T> T get(String key)
    {
        return (T) preferences.getAll().get(key);
    }


    public <T> T getDefault(String key, T defaultValue)
    {
        T storedValue = get(key);

        return storedValue == null ? defaultValue : storedValue;
    }
}
```

Now to use sharedprefrences in `FlutterActivity`

```
@Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
        SharedPreferencesHandler preferencesHandler = new SharedPreferencesHandler(getApplicationContext());
        new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
                .setMethodCallHandler(
                        (call, result) -> {
                            if(call.method.equals("saveData")){
                                preferencesHandler.put("name", call.argument("name"));
                                preferencesHandler.put("email", call.argument("email"));
                                preferencesHandler.apply();
                                result.success(true);
                            } else {
                                result.notImplemented();
                            }
                        }
                );
    }
```